# Reactjs Subdirectory not loading on IIS Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iis, service-worker

I have an app A hosted on IIS Server at some url https://www.a.com . I have another app B (react app) which i want to host on the url  https://www.a.com/b.

I used webpack to build the react code.

And I am getting the error in sw.js i.e "Wrong Response Status". I am also using React-router to establish routes. And have changed the basename also. But this doesn't work.

The code i Wrote in index.js is as follows :-

```
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/b' });
 <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={ClaimsMainForm} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/claims-dashboard" component={ClaimsDashboard} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/claims-reports" component={ClaimsReports} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/preauth-hosp/:operation?" component={PreAuthorizationHospForm} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/preauth-tpa" component={PreAuthorizationTpaform} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/preauth-coordinator" component={PreAuthorizationCoordinatorForm} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/claims-cashless" component={CashlessClaimsForm} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/privacy-policy" component={PrivacyPolicy} />
        <Route path="/terms-and-conditions" component={TnC} />
        <Route path="/disclaimer" component={Disclaimer} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
```

Please Help!

Comment: @Snehalata...did you found any solution for this? I am also struggling with this same issue